# Update query with lots of case expressions - How to avoid empty updates?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Sample Query

```
UPDATE table_name tn SET 
        col1 = CASE WHEN col1 = 'x' THEN 'X' WHEN col1 = 'y' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Z' END,
        col2 = CASE WHEN col2 = 'x' THEN 'X' WHEN col2 = 'y' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Z' END,
        col3 = CASE WHEN col3 = 'x' THEN 'X' WHEN col3 = 'y' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Z'
        END
        FROM temp_table tt
        WHERE tn.id = tt.id AND 
    ( col1 IS DISTINCT FROM (CASE WHEN col1 = 'x' THEN 'X' WHEN col1 = 'y' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Z' END) 
OR col2 IS DISTINCT FROM (CASE WHEN col2 = 'x' THEN 'X' WHEN col2 = 'y' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Z' END) 
OR (col3 IS DISTINCT FROM (CASE WHEN col3 = 'x' THEN 'X' WHEN col3 = 'y' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Z' END) )
```

For the above query to avoid empty updates, we can formulate the query as

```
WITH tmp AS
(
SELECT id, col1 = CASE WHEN col1 = 'x' THEN 'X' WHEN col1 = 'y' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Z' END,
            col2 = CASE WHEN col2 = 'x' THEN 'X' WHEN col2 = 'y' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Z' END column2,
            col3 = CASE WHEN col3 = 'x' THEN 'X' WHEN col3 = 'y' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Z' AS coloumn3
FROM temp_table
)
UPDATE table_name tn SET col1 = tmp.column1, col2 = tmp.column2, col3 = tmp.column3
FROM tmp
WHERE tmp.id = tn.id AND
      (tn.col1 IS DISTINCT FROM tmp.column1 OR
       tn.col2 IS DISTINCT FROM tmp.column2 OR
       tn.col3 IS DISTINCT FROM tmp.column3
      )
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks,
Shankar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postgres, you can use row constructors:

```
WITH tmp AS (
      SELECT id, col1 = CASE WHEN col1 = 'x' THEN 'X' WHEN col1 = 'y' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Z' END,
             col2 = CASE WHEN col2 = 'x' THEN 'X' WHEN col2 = 'y' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Z' END column2,
             col3 = CASE WHEN col3 = 'x' THEN 'X' WHEN col3 = 'y' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Z' AS coloumn3
      FROM temp_table
     )
UPDATE table_name tn
    SET (col1, col2, col3) = (tmp.column1, tmp.column2, tmp.column3
FROM tmp
WHERE tmp.id = tn.id AND
      (tn.col1, tn.col2, tn.col3) IS DISTINCT FROM (tmp.column1, tmp.column2, temp.column3);
```